# Configuring C++ SDK in Intellij IDEA for Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure Intellij to create C/C++ projects. The plugin was installed successfully but when I go to create a new project, I have to setup a Cpp SDK. Is This a path  to GCC home or similar (I try it but doesn't works)? How can I perform this configuration?

Comment: Haha, is `visual studio` suddenly not good enough for the c++ world?

Comment: @vikingsteve JetBrains is coming with a cross platform c++ IDE soon: http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/features/cpp.html

Comment: Hi @vikingsteve I bought Intellij IDEA 13. I'll like to develop in only one IDE that I use about 5 years and I've mastered all shortcuts and tricks. But, thank you.

Comment: I don't know anything about the C++-plugin to IntelliJ, but I have used CLion - JetBrains's new specialized C/C++ IDE - a lot the last year, and I think it's great. It's built on the IDEA platform, so the key bindings, all the editor features and the generale look and feel are the same as in IntelliJ. Because developing for C/C++ is so relatively different from developing for Java, I think a specialized IDE gives you a much better experience. You should at least try it out before you dismiss it, I don't think you will regret it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cpptools.com/IDEA/Readme.html) is detailed about the configuration:

> Install the plugin. There will appear no special project type for C/C++ projects. Just take/create any Java project, and the plugin will process all `*.c`/`*.cc`/`*.cpp` source files from the project source roots.
>
> Then you need to specify the C/C++ dialect. Open **Settings->IDE Settings->C/C++**. There are three options, which can be used for tuning:
>
> - **Compiler selector** — you may choose between GCC and MS VC dialects
> - **Use C dialect** — this option makes the compiler to treat the sources like C, not CPP files.
> - **GCC executable name** — `gcc` is used if this field is left blank. This option is important for GCC configuration autodetection.
>
> To parse the files you also need to specify include paths for your C/C++ environment. Currently, the plugin can automatically detect GCC include paths, in case of other compilers you need to specify the include paths by yourself. Additional include files can be specified for each project separately. **Automatic gcc include paths detection works only if your compiler presents in path**. If it does not (or if you want to use include-paths of a non-default compiler), then you should specify the name (full name, if necessary) of gcc executable in GCC executable name field.

**UPDATE:** I would suggest you to try JetBrain's [CLion - The intelligent cross-platform C/C++ IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) for cross platform development.
If you are using Visual Studio then use [Resharper C++](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper-cpp/). ReSharper C++ makes Microsoft Visual Studio a much better IDE with refactorings, navigation, code inspections, quick-fixes, code generation and more productivity features for C++ development.